# How to assign returned data from a new assigned method to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In Python3, I need to return data from a file that is selected with QFileDialog. I assigned a new method to QLineEdit object (self.ui.my_file_lineEdit) to be able to open QFileDialog when clicking on it but how do I assign that data (file content) to a variable?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from mainwindow import *


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):
        """Initializing GUI from mainwindow module"""
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #opens a file for selecting my_file.csv
        self.ui.my_file_lineEdit.mouseReleaseEvent = self.openfile_Dialog


    def openfile_Dialog(self, event):
        """
        Opens a dialog for choosing a file. Takes two positionals
        arguments 'self' and 'event' because 'mouseReleaseEvent' sends two
        """
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "/home")
        if fname[0]:
            f = open(fname[0], "r")
            with f:
                data = f.read()
                return data
                #self.ui.textBrowser.setText(data)
```

When I select a file at the momonet I get an error:

> TypeError: invalid result from Main.openfile_Dialog()

I would like to assign a variable to a content of that file. Something like:

```
self.my_variable = self.ui.lista_lineEdit.mouseReleaseEvent = self.openfile_Dialog
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I realize you want the content, just call your method to assign:

```
self.my_variable = self.ui.lista_lineEdit.mouseReleaseEvent = self.openfile_Dialog()
```

You forgot about calling the method, the way you are assigning is to the reference of the method itself.

Comment: I don't wont to call a method right now. I want to call it only when I click QLineEdit widget. But, you are right, I didn't know I could use `=` two times